# login as user X rejected

Tags: login, authentication, su, useradd

Adding a user like so:

```
sudo useradd juliet -p juliet -s /bin/sh
```

and then typing

```
su - juliet
Password:
```

Get the error: su: **Authentication failure**

Why? And how do I change user?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `useradd` to create a password as it is a special type of password. From **useradd** manual, -**p** flag:

> -p: The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The
> default is to disable the password. Note: This option is not recommended because the password
> (or encrypted password) will be visible by users listing
> the processes.

So the commands should be:

```
sudo useradd juliet -s /bin/sh
sudo passwd juliet #and type the password
```